# Inject bean by CDI from different deployment

Tags: java, jboss, cdi

This might be a bit complex.

I have an `EAR` and a `WAR` deployed in a `JBoss 7` container side by side.
The `EAR` has a `service.jar` module with `EJBs` and in its `lib` folder there is another utility jar. In the utility jar there is a resource producer class, like this:

```
public class BaseResources {

@Produces
private Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
    String category = ip.getMember()
            .getDeclaringClass()
            .getName();
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(category);
}
}
```

Now the WAR depends on the EAR and sees all its classes.

But when I try to inject a `Logger` instance into a class in the `WAR`, there is a `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point` thrown, telling me there is no `Logger` instance to inject.

Is there a way to inject the `Logger` into a class in the `WAR`?

Comment: I suspect this is not possible, but i hope i'm wrong about that.

Comment: Is the war in the ear? (is the logger get injected in the ear class?)

Comment: If it's outside the EAR, no this is not possible. Those are two completely separate deployments. The two deployments can't even see the classes of each other because of the classloader isolation. You'd need to package the war with the ear in this case.

Comment: do you specify module dependencies of your WAR using jboss-deployment-structure.xml?